# Consulta em tabelas muito grandes demora? Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que espero ficar grande no futuro e estou com um dilema: armazenar um array nos dados de cada usuários ou criar uma tabela específica com todas essas informações misturadas

(Ex: carros de cada usuário)

Minha pergunta é:

Se eu fizer uma tabela e ela tiver digamos 500.000 linhas, isso causará algum atraso na hora do sql percorrer ela para me retornar os dados?

Armazenar arrays em tabelas é uma boa prática de programação?

Answer (score 1):

**Armazenar arrays em tabelas é uma boa prática de programação?**

Banco de dados não salva Array, e sim String, como o `JSON`. Então veja que da na mesma que salvar como string. O problema fica na manutenção e não na performance. Se é uma boa prática de programação, **não**, pois prejudica principalmente a documentação, e portanto, a manutenibilidade. Mas cada caso é um caso, as vezes a informação do Array é pouco reutilizável no sistema e dividi-lo no banco, poderia sobrecarregar o banco de dados com tabelas.

**Se eu fizer uma tabela e ela tiver digamos 500.000 linhas, isso causará algum atraso na hora do sql percorrer ela para me retornar os dados?**

É lógico que um banco de dados tende a ficar mais lento conforme a quantidade de registro, isso é inevitável. Mas você pode reduzir a quantidade de atributos do SELECT, tornando o processo de transferência mais rápido. Porém isso não é possível fazer se o dado estiver dentro de um `ARRAY`.